# Windows Powershell code numerical sequential increments for variables

Tags: powershell

I'm a (very new) beginner with powershell and need help inputting a code that will add a comma and numerical increment to each line of output which would be a random number. The output is displayed in a file.

```
$file = "path to file"


for ($i=0; $i -le 4; $i++) {
    $a = Get-Random -Minimum 10 -Maximum 50
    Add-Content $file $a.ToString("0")
}
```

so the output of this would be 1 line for each random number such as:

```
12
30
22
41.. etc
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
1,12
2,35
3,22
4,41
```

Can anyone please provide a code that would make this happen? any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$file = "C:\Temp\test.txt"
for ($i=1; $i -le 5; $i++) {
    $a = Get-Random -Minimum 10 -Maximum 50
    $line = $i.ToString() + "," + $a.ToString()
    Add-Content $file $line
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a more PowerShell-idiomatic solution that uses the *pipeline* (`|`):

```
1..4 | ForEach-Object { '{0},{1}' -f  $_, (Get-Random -Min 10 -max 50) } | Set-Content $file
```

- `1..4` uses the range operator (`..`) to create an array of integers from `1` to `4`, inclusively.
- `ForEach-Object` invokes the associated script block (`{ ... }`) for each input object (integer in this case) represented as automatic variable `$_`:

  - `'{0},{1}' -f $_, (Get-Random -Min 10 -max 50)` uses the the string-formatting operator (`-f`), whose LHS is a format string containing positional placeholders for the RHS values (`{0}` is  placeholder for the 1st argument, ...), to produce an output string containing the integer at hand, followed by comma and the random number.
- `Set-Content` saves all strings it receives to output file `$file` (using the default character encoding, which in Windows PowerShell is the "ANSI" encoding implied by the legacy system locale; use parameter `-Encoding` to change that).

Comment: I was about posting the short version `1..4|%{"{0},{1}" -f $_,(Get-Random -Min 10 -max 50)}|sc $file` (to be accompanied by the long one) before I scrolled down and saw your answer. ;-)

Comment: @LotPings :) On a side note: alias `sc` was removed from PowerShell _Core_.